# .htaccess redirect from subfolder to domain not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, friendly-url

I am using PHP, Laravel 8 Framework, and cPanel for my website. What I am trying to do is something like this.

**Redirecting Routes from**

```
http://example.com/example.com/public/
http://example.com/example.com/public/about
http://example.com/example.com/public/contact
.
.
// more
```

**to**

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/about
https://example.com/contact
.
.
// more
```

I have the `.htaccess` file in the domain root `public_html` folder.

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /example.com/public/$1 [L]
```

Please guide me if I had done something wrong.

Comment: Could you please do let us know are these only Rules present in your htaccess file OR you have more rules in it?

Comment: I have only this much and `example.com/public` folder I have laravel default  htaccess file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following rules, with your shown attempts. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Make sure 2 things. 1st- Keep your htaccess rules file in same level where you have folder example.com and 2nd- keep your index.php inside /root/example.com/public folder.

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example\.com/public [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ example.com/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ example.com/public/index.php [L]
```